# How to pass default value loaded into form input to the payload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making an edit form which inside Modal. Form inputs has defaultValue that comes from props with an name, age and strength as default value. If I change all inputs value, everything works fine, but if I change only one input value when I console.log payload I got and empty strings, but only value that I changed goes to the payload. [image: Console.log] How can I make that even I change only one input payload gets inputs default value from props?

My code is here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Form.scss';
import axios from 'axios';

class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: this.props.gnomeId,
            submitedName: '',
            submitedAge: '',
            submitedStrength: ''
        }
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        });
    }

    onSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const gnome = {
                name: this.state.submitedName,
                age: this.state.submitedAge,
                strenght: this.state.submitedStrength,
              }
        console.log(gnome);

        axios.post(`${API}/${this.state.id}`, {gnome})
        .then( res => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="submitedName" id="name" defaultValue={this.props.gnomeName} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="age">Age</label>
                    <input type="text" name="submitedAge" id="age" defaultValue={this.props.gnomeAge} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="strength">Strength</label>
                    <input type="text" name="submitedStrength" id="strength" defaultValue={this.props.gnomeStrength} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="submit-btn">Submit</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the initial state to the default values:

```
super(props);
this.state = {
    id: this.props.gnomeId,
    submitedName: props.gnomeName,
    submitedAge: props.gnomeAge,
    submitedStrength: props.gnomeStrength
}
```

Comment: Set state from props is not best practice, refer to official [document](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

Comment: ^ you may search above document using the key `Avoid copying props into state`

Comment: you mean the part where it says "Only use this pattern if you intentionally want to ignore prop updates", which is what you want to do with default form values?

Comment: There are so many solutions, just avoid using this pattern. No need to walk by the river as well as trying to keep yourself dry.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Nullish_Coalescing_Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_Coalescing_Operator) to give different value from init as null/undefined

```
this.state = {
  submitedName: null,
  ...
}

const gnome = {
  name: this.state.submitedName ?? this.props.submitedName,
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First remove the defaultProps.
add **componentDidUpdate** in class based component and **useEffect** in function based component

```
componentDidUpdate(props) {
  if(props){
    this.state = {
      id: this.props.gnomeId,
      submitedName: props.gnomeName,
      submitedAge: props.gnomeAge,
      submitedStrength: props.gnomeStrength
    }
  }
}
```

it is necessary to put props in if because it has undefined initial so not to get error